# how to update dictionary dynamically in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to update dictionary dynamically

```
for I in range(0,4):
    var = method(I) # var = "abc:def:ghi:1234"
    [a,b,c,d]= var.split(':')
    d = d.rstrip('\n')
    rdict = {i:d}
    rdict = rdict .update({i:d})
```

But problem is if I print rdict, it is not printing. I,m missing some basic steps. Please help on this.

Answer (score 5):

`rdict.update` modifies the dictionary in-place and returns `None`. Don't assign that value back to `rdict`.

```
rdict = {}
for i in range(0,4):
    var = "abc:def:ghi:1234"
    [a,b,c,d]= var.split(':')
    d = d.rstrip('\n')
    rdict.update({i:d})
```

Most of the code in the loop is independent of `i`, and could be moved outside the loop. In fact, a much more idiomatic way to create `rdict` would be

```
rdict = dict((i, var.split(':')[3]) for i in range(4))
```

or

```
# Python 2.7 or later
rdict = {i: var.split(':')[3] for i in range(4)}
```

If `var` is dependent on `i`, then

```
rdict = {}
for i in range(4):
    a, b, c, d = method(i)
    d = d.rstrip('\n')
    rdict[i] = d   # More efficient than calling update
```

Comment: I'd except result like {0:1234,1:1234,2:1234,3:1234} but after your recommend I am printing outside for loop rdict returning {3:1234} Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to set `rdict = {}` *before* the loop starts, and get rid of the assignment to `rdict` inside the loop.

Comment: rdict = {}                                                                                                                    for i in range(0,4):
    var = "abc:def:ghi:1234"
    [a,b,c,d]= var.split(':')
    d = d.rstrip('\n')
    rdict = {i:d}
    rdict.update({i:d}) but it doesn't help, still same result.{3:1234}

Comment: You didn't get rid of the assignment *inside* the loop, which resets the value of `rdict`

Comment: @ chepner , could you please tell me how to get rid of this assignment by code snippet?

Comment: rdict = {}
for i in range(0,4):                                                                                                                method(i) --> I miss this statement in the question
    var = "abc:def:ghi:1234"    
    [a,b,c,d]= var.split(':')
    d = d.rstrip('\n')
    rdict.update({i:d})  code in the loop is dependent of I, How could I solve this?

Comment: for I in range(0,4):
    var = method(I) # var = "abc:def:ghi:1234"
    [a,b,c,d]= var.split(':')
    d = d.rstrip('\n')
    rdict = {i:d}
    rdict = rdict .update({i:d})